# How to install Lazarus on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, lazarus

I have installed Lazarus from the Ubuntu Software Center before, but yesterday I tried to install Ubuntu on my Mac and I don't see Lazarus listed.

Does anyone have a URL for the Ubuntu installation or the code that I can use to install it at the command prompt? Might I find it at https://snapcraft.io/?q=lazarus&op= ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try installing it via terminal

```
sudo apt-get install lazarus-ide
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks, i try to install at home today and return! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Getting Lazarus from Ubuntu  repository**

BEWARE: THIS PAGE IS OUTDATED.

```
sudo apt-get install lazarus-ide
```

---

**Getting Lazarus from freepascal  repository**

Add the key

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:11371 --recv-keys 6A11800F; gpg -a --export 6A11800F | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the repository

```
echo "deb http://www.hu.freepascal.org/lazarus/ lazarus-stable universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lazarus-stable.list
```

Installtion

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install lazarus
```

[Source](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_release_version_for_Ubuntu)

Comment: You are correct. I tried the chosen answer and it complained that it can find FPC when tried to run it. Your answer worked flawlessly...

Comment: That worked but now I get this:  http://www.hu.freepascal.org/lazarus/dists/lazarus-stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 13A5146226002BBC25E32D23670C48C26A11800F uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)...

Comment: Solution still works on a fresh Lubuntu install. You saved a friend of mine of a pesky commute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu installed, you can install a version of Lazarus from the the software repisitories. The desktop icon should look like this:[image]
[image]

Comment: Whats the repository? Because my ubuntu is clear, and i seach a ubuntu, don't receive a result. I try at home and return. Thanks.

Comment: See my edited reply.